# Set Values for Nested Class

Tags: c#, reflection

I have two classes:

```
public class Task {
    public int TaskId {get; set;}
    public string Desc {get; set;}
    public Client taskClient {get; set;}
}

public class Client {
    public string Firstname {get;set;}
    public string Lastname {get;set;}
    ...(other 18 properties)
}
```

I have lists of values (about 100) with the following structure:

```
TaskId = 1, Desc = "Task 1", Firstname = "Mark", Lastname ="Smith".
```

How can I create new tasks using reflection in this case?

Comment: You can get `taskClient` property value, and then get `FirstName` value. it will be two reflection operation

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: So you need to set inner property values or create new tasks ?

Comment: @OrelEraki I need to create new ones

Comment: Why can't you just have a constructor for `Task` that takes an int, string and `Client` and then a constructor for `Client` that takes two strings?

Comment: @shortspider I actually have about 20 properties in my Client class and just to simplify the example of what I need to achieve, I cut it to 2 only.

Comment: Fair enough. I would either have some kind of factory method that takes the list of values and creates a new `Task` using [Object Initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx) or do what @SergeyLitvinov suggested and do two reflection operations.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object with the [Activator Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and fill in the values via reflection.

```
var clientType = typeof(Client);
var c = Activator.CreateInstance(clientType);
clientType.GetProperty("Firstname").SetValue(c, "Mark");
clientType.GetProperty("Lastname").SetValue(c, "Smith");

var taskType = typeof(Task);
var t = Activator.CreateInstance(taskType);
taskType.GetProperty("TaskId").SetValue(t, 1);
taskType.GetProperty("Desc").SetValue(t, "Task 1");
taskType.GetProperty("taskClient").SetValue(t, c);
```